# Unable to set Nuka Carousel slide content height

Tags: reactjs

I can't get the content of my nuka-carousel slides to be the same height. Setting `heightMode="max"` on the carousel sets the slide heights equal, but trying to expand the slide content isn't working right.

I've tried setting height on the slides to `100%`, `inherit`, `100vh` but no matter what, the slides expand to maybe 2-20x what they should be (depending on the div with the most content).

I've also tried using flexbox with `flex:1` and I've tried with css-grid. Nothing seems to help

```
const Item = ({ children }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      boxShadow: "rgb(153, 153, 153) 2px 2px 4px 2px"
      // height: "100%"
      // height: "100vh"
      /// height: 'inherit'
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </div>
);

<Carousel
    wrapAround
    heightMode="max"
    slidesToShow={1.25}
    cellAlign="center">
        {/* Item components with varying content */}
</Carousel>
```

Here's a codesandbox, If anyone has any suggestions I'd appreciate it. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-khorana-bowrz?file=/src/index.js